# How to write this in shorthand javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, shorthand

I know how to write one line in a shorthand javascript if else statement.
I am not sure how to write two. I keep getting an error with my syntax.
This is what I am trying to convert into shorthand.

```
if (node === newValue) {
  console.log('did find case') 
  return true
} else {
  console.log('didn\'t find case') 
}
```

I am trying to convert the above code into this but I am receiving an error

```
  node === newValue
    ? console.log('did find case') 
      true
    : console.log('didn\'t find case')
```

Comment: Why you want to make the code short when it's readable?

Comment: I agree with @Tushar, that theres something to be said for leaving your code readable. If you're worried about file size, consider using a js minifying service like [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2)

Comment: Since console.log is used for debugging, I would change the code to **return (node === newValue);**  Code structure shouldn't change to support debugging.

Comment: @user2182349: In OP's code, there is no return in the else case.

Comment: @Amadan - There is no function statement either, it is likely there is more code and entirely possible the function terminates after the if statement.

Comment: @user2182349: That is likely true. Be that as it may, the two are not equivalent. Being led to think not-equivalent things are equivalent is what got OP in this mess in the first place. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?:` and `if` are not equivalent, and in particular one shouldn't think of `?:` as a "shorthand `if`". `if` works on statements and statement blocks; `?:` works on expressions. While all expressions are statements and many statements are also expressions, `return` is not an expression: there is no way to use it inside `?:`.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot more sense. 
I will have to go back and review the fundamentals